# How I can close a text file after I edited?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a text file `installer_input.txt` and a `checkedListBox2` in a `form application`. I want to edit the text file if I have some changes in `checkesListBox2`. I have two parts of code, I know that are so long, but I need some help :

```
 private void checkedListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
            var lin = (path + "config.ini").ToString();
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(lin);
            string InstallerFile = lines.Where(txt => txt.Contains("IstallerFile="))
                        .Select(txt => txt.Split('=')[1].Replace("\"", "")).FirstOrDefault();
             string pathTemp = @"C:\temp\";
            string[] pathArr = InstallerFile.Split('\\');
            string[] fileArr = pathArr.Last().Split('\\');
            string fileArr1 = String.Join(" ", fileArr);


            string installerfilename = string.Format("{0}{1}", pathTemp, fileArr1);
            IEnumerable<string> inilines = File.ReadAllLines(installerfilename).AsEnumerable();
            bool IsChecked = checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Contains(checkedListBox2.SelectedItem);
 else if (fileArr1.Equals("installer_input.txt"))
            {
                if (IsChecked && checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count != checkedListBox2.Items.Count)
                    inilines = inilines.Select(line => line == string.Format("#product.{0}", checkedListBox2.SelectedItem)
                                                       ? Regex.Replace(line, string.Format("#product.{0}", checkedListBox2.SelectedItem), string.Format(@"product.{0}", checkedListBox2.SelectedItem))
                                                       : line);
                else if (!IsChecked || checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count == checkedListBox2.Items.Count)
                    inilines = inilines.Select(line => (line == string.Format("product.{0}", checkedListBox2.SelectedItem))
                                                       ? Regex.Replace(line, string.Format(@".*product.{0}", checkedListBox2.SelectedItem), string.Format(@"#product.{0}", checkedListBox2.SelectedItem))
                                                       : line);
                if (checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count == checkedListBox2.Items.Count)
                    checkBox1.Checked = true;

                else
                    checkBox1.Checked = false;

                string strWrite = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, inilines.ToArray());
                File.WriteAllText(installerfilename, strWrite);

            }
        }
```

And the second code is :

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
            SetAllItemsChecked(cb.Checked);

            var installerLines = ReadInstallerLines();
            SetAllProductsChecked(installerLines.ToList(), cb.Checked);
            SaveInstaller(installerLines);
        }

        private void SetAllItemsChecked(bool check)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.checkedListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                this.checkedListBox2.SetItemChecked(i, check);
            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<string> ReadInstallerLines()
        {
            var lin = (path + "config.ini").ToString();
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(lin);
            string InstallerFile = lines.Where(txt => txt.Contains("IstallerFile="))
                        .Select(txt => txt.Split('=')[1].Replace("\"", "")).FirstOrDefault();
            string pathTemp = @"C:\temp\";
            string[] pathArr = InstallerFile.Split('\\');
            string[] fileArr = pathArr.Last().Split('\\');
            string fileArr1 = String.Join(" ", fileArr);
            string installerfilename = pathTemp + fileArr1;
            string installertext = File.ReadAllText(installerfilename);
            return File.ReadLines(pathTemp + fileArr1);
        }

        private void SetAllProductsChecked(IList<string> installerLines, bool check)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < installerLines.Count; i++)
            {
                if (installerLines[i].Contains("product="))
                {
                    installerLines[i] = check
                        ? installerLines[i].Replace("#product", "product")
                        : installerLines[i].Replace("product", "#product");
                }
                if (installerLines[i].Contains("product."))
                {
                    installerLines[i] = check
                        ?installerLines[i].Replace("#product.", "product.")
                         : installerLines[i].Replace("product.", "#product.");
                }
            }
        }

        private void SaveInstaller(IEnumerable<string> installerLines)
        {
            var lin = (path + "config.ini").ToString();
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(lin);
            string InstallerFile = lines.Where(txt => txt.Contains("IstallerFile="))
                        .Select(txt => txt.Split('=')[1].Replace("\"", "")).FirstOrDefault();
            string pathTemp = @"C:\temp\";
            string[] pathArr = InstallerFile.Split('\\');
            string[] fileArr = pathArr.Last().Split('\\');
            string fileArr1 = String.Join(" ", fileArr);
            string installerfilename = pathTemp + fileArr1;         
            File.WriteAllLines(installerfilename, installerLines);
        }
    }
```

First works, I can check the boxes from the list, but when I try to make click on checkBox1 I have the next error: `The process cannot access the file 'C:\temp\installer_input.txt' because it is used by another process`.
How I can make program to works? And how I can optimize my code ?

Comment: Try using `File.ReadAllLines` instead of `File.ReadLines`.

Comment: Wouu... Thank you so much ! And you can help me wit the optimization ?

Comment: No, if the code works, but you think it can/should be optimized, repost the working code on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) and ask for help there.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen About the code ... I have a problem .. The method SetallProductsChecked  change the rows from text file but don't save the file. Way ?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I put  SaveInstaller(installerLines);in SetallProductsChecked method  but the same thing ..

Answer (score 0):

Basically a single thread/process can access a resource which is the file in this case at one instance what you can do is use [EventWaitHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx) to wait untill some other process or thread has occupied the file like this:

```
EventWaitHandle waitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(true, EventResetMode.AutoReset, "SHARED_BY_ALL_PROCESSES");
waitHandle.WaitOne();
/* process file*/
waitHandle.Set();
```