# How to write # before product if I have the checkBox selected and delete if not?

Tags: c#

I have a text file `installer_input.ini` and it is like this:

```
Rows
... 
product.name1
product.name2
...
product.nameN
...
Rows
```

In a form application I have a CheckBox1 to select/deselect all items from the ChecedListBox2 and for this I use next code :

```
 private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
     var lin = (path + "config.ini").ToString();
     var lines = File.ReadAllLines(lin);
     string InstallerFile = lines.Where(txt => txt.Contains("IstallerFile="))
                                 .Select(txt => txt.Split('=')[1].Replace("\"", ""))
                                 .FirstOrDefault();
     string pathTemp = @"C:\temp\";
     string[] pathArr = InstallerFile.Split('\\');
     string[] fileArr = pathArr.Last().Split('\\');
     string fileArr1 = String.Join(" ", fileArr);

     string installerfilename = pathTemp + fileArr1;
     string installertext = File.ReadAllText(installerfilename);
     var linInst = File.ReadLines(pathTemp + fileArr1).ToArray();

     if (this.ActiveControl != sender)
         return;

     CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
     if ((cb.Checked) && (checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count != checkedListBox2.Items.Count))
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < this.checkedListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
         {
             this.checkedListBox2.SetItemChecked(i, true);        
         }
     }
     else if ((!cb.Checked) && ((checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count != checkedListBox2.Items.Count) || (checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count == checkedListBox2.Items.Count)))
     {                  
         //checkBox1.Checked = false;
         for (int i = 0; i < this.checkedListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
         {
             this.checkedListBox2.SetItemChecked(i, false);                            
         }
     }
}
```

And when checkBox1 is select I want to write `#` before `product.` and if the checkBox1 is deselected to delete `#` before `product`.
Until now I tried a lot of variants but not works properly . So how I can do this ?

I know already exists a similar question, but I already tried and don't works in my case .

Comment: `txt.Contains("IstallerFile="))`  => typo?

Comment: You can help me, please, with the code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace product to #product?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32838492/how-to-replace-product-to-product)

Comment: or you want to say with this newInstaller1 = newInstaller1.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, "product.", "#product." )); ???

Comment: @venerik I already tried with that but don't works ...

Comment: Is product added into checkedListBox?

Comment: @Rakesh yes, It's added

Answer (score 0):

Modify for loop like below and try

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.checkedListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
             {
                 this.checkedListBox2.SetItemChecked(i, true);   
                 checkedListBox2.Items[i]=checkedListBox2.Items[i].ToString().Replace("product","#product");
             }

    for (int i = 0; i < this.checkedListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
             {
                 this.checkedListBox2.SetItemChecked(i, false);       
    checkedListBox2.Items[i]=checkedListBox2.Items[i].ToString().Replace("#product","product");                     
             }
```